# How to fix Google Firestore issue in Elixir?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, elixir

I always run into an issue, when calling: `GoogleApi.Firestore.V1beta1.Api.Projects.firestore_projects_databases_documents_run_query()`, as shown below.

I already tried different inputs and formatting ways, as well as different firestore collections.

```elixir
{:ok, token} = Goth.Token.for_scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform")

conn = GoogleApi.Firestore.V1beta1.Connection.new(token.token)

query = %GoogleApi.Firestore.V1beta1.Model.RunQueryRequest{
  structuredQuery: %{
    :from => %{:collectionId => "demo"},
    :limit => 1
  }
}

GoogleApi.Firestore.V1beta1.Api.Projects.firestore_projects_databases_documents_run_query(
  conn,
  "projects/demo/databases/(default)/documents",
  body: query
)
```

Result:

```elixir
** (BadMapError) expected a map, got: [%{"readTime" => "2019-04-07T20:23:48.219664Z"}]
    (elixir) lib/map.ex:437: Map.get([%{"readTime" => "2019-04-07T20:23:48.219664Z"}], "document", nil)
    lib/poison/decoder.ex:53: anonymous fn/3 in Poison.Decode.transform_struct/4
    (stdlib) maps.erl:257: :maps.fold_1/3
    lib/poison/decoder.ex:52: Poison.Decode.transform_struct/4
    lib/poison.ex:70: Poison.decode/2
```

Comment: Hi @dominik, interestingly i have the same error; anyway i started using your example to understand how the library worked, since the total lack of examples (even in the test folder :/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what it's worth, I've managed to load a document by doing the following:

```elixir
{:ok, token} = Goth.Token.for_scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore")
conn = GoogleApi.Firestore.V1.Connection.new(token.token)
{:ok, document} = GoogleApi.Firestore.V1.Api.Projects.firestore_projects_databases_documents_get(
  conn,
  "projects/{project_id}/databases/(default)/documents/{collection_id}/{document_id}"
)
```

where the variables `{XXX}` are replaced with the actual values.

Maybe not exactly your use case but since examples of using Firestore in Elixir are hard to find, this might be useful to someone!